# How to read a specific line from 2 text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, readline

I am creating a program that is supposed to ReadLine text into a 2 text file
I am able to read the text from the text file but I do not know how to control a specific line.

Number1.txt lines

```
1:1
2:2
3:3
4:4
5:5
6:6
...
EOF
```

Number2.txt lines

```
Save
Skip
Discount
...
EOF
```

I want Read Line Output :-

```
1:1 save
2:2 save
3:3 save
1:1 Skip
2:2 Skip
3:3 Skip
1:1 Discount
2:2 Discount
3:3 Discount
4:4 save
5:5 save
6:6 save
4:4 Skip
5:5 Skip
6:6 Skip
4:4 Discount
5:5 Discount
6:6 Discount
...
EOF
```

3 lines text1 To 1 line text2 
iF EOF text2 exit loop
i cant Write this Code Please Help me 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A little lost on what you're asking here.  Are you creating the text files or are you reading them?  Are you able to give us what you've done so far and highlight the specific problem your having?

Comment: i want reading from file

Comment: So what specifically is your problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read 1 & 2 & 3 lines From file1.txt and give First Line from file2.txt  example File2.txt  First Line John , and read  
John line1 From file1
John line2 From file1
John line2 From file1
if Finish John Go to Second Line from File2.txt if finish File2.txt
Go To New 3 Lines From file1.txt ( 4 & 5 &6)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't think of this I've spent most of the time working on this

Comment: Ok, so what code have you done so far?  Show us the code and we will be able to help

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 nested loops. But I would create a helper function as iterator. This makes it easier to use the output.

```
Private Shared Iterator Function Combine(
    ByVal numbers1 As String(), ByVal numbers2 As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)

    Dim repetitions As Integer = 3

    Dim i1 As Integer = 0
    While i1 < numbers1.Length
        For i2 As Integer = 0 To numbers2.Length - 1
            Dim rep As Integer = 0
            While rep < repetitions AndAlso i1 + rep < numbers1.Length
                Yield $"{numbers1(i1 + rep)} {numbers2(i2)}"
                rep += 1
            End While
        Next
        i1 += repetitions
    End While
End Function
```

The deepest nested While-loop also tests `i1 + rep < numbers1.Length` to ensure that `Number1.txt` files having a number of lines not being multiples of 3 do not throw an index out of bound exception.

Then you can write the output file with

```
Dim numbers1 As String() = File.ReadAllLines("Number1.txt")
Dim numbers2 As String() = File.ReadAllLines("Number2.txt")
File.WriteAllLines("File3.txt", Combine(numbers1, numbers2))
```

See also:

- [Iterators (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) (Microsoft Docs)
- [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: You did not specify what kind of output you need. This is just an example of an output.

Comment: i can output From File3.txt ?

Comment: numbers1 can line.Split(":")

Comment: very thanks Oliver 
i have last Question
this is correct
Dim str() As String
str = numbers1(i1 + rep).Split(":")
if End numbers1 lines show error

Comment: For me this works: `Dim str As String() = numbers1(i1 + rep).Split(":"c)`. Note the **c** after `":"`. This makes it a`Char`, which is needed by `Split`.

Comment: Of course it works great but when it comes to the end of the line Number1.txt
Stop project and show this massege IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Comment: Thank you very much ... I wish you success

Comment: You must debug your code. See: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).